# Rails 4 active record model has_many through associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I been struggling with this concept for some time. I read the guide and still - I am having a hard time getting this to work as I need it to. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

For me this topic has been difficult to understand because of all the conventions. My code below is an attempt. Please feel free to offer suggestions for best practices besides error corrections if you see fit. Thanks a million!

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shorturls, through: :campaigns
end

class Shorturl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners, through: :campaigns
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :shorturl
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shorturl
end
```

What I would like to do is go to `url/campaign` to create a new record with a nested form which has `owner` and `shorturl` params.

The form that I have looks like this:

```
<h1>New Campaign</h1>

<%= form_for :campaign do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :shorturl do |shorturl| %>
    <%= shorturl.label :redirect %><br>
    <%= shorturl.text_field :redirect %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :owner do |owner| %>
    <%= owner.label :email %><br>
    <%= owner.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

The `Routes` are setup as follows:

```
post '/campaign', to: 'campaign#create'
get '/campaign', to: 'campaign#index'
```

My `Campaign#controller` looks like this:

```
class CampaignController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @campaign = Campaign.new
  end

  def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @campaign.save
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @campaign }
      else
        format.json { render json: @campaign.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    private
    def set_campaign
      @campaign = campaign.find(params[:id])
    end

    def campaign_params
      params.require(:campaign).permit(shorturl_attributes: [:redirect], owner_attributes: [:email])
    end
end
```

As of now when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in CampaignController#create
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

What is wrong with the above? Thanks again!

## update after changing the respond_to block format, I am getting an unpermitted_params error: see logs:

```
Started POST "/campaign" for ::1 at 2014-10-17 21:04:08 -0400
Processing by CampaignController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9VOe+9VDhVaXR/eJKxA8PUJdZGoRQQZvWpfdX0SeDZrzL1gTVICMTjQkR+rk43WPSAxLz7s73YwhF1HdV8Qazg==", "campaign"=>{"shorturl"=>{"redirect"=>"http://www.somesite.com"}, "owner"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com"}}, "commit"=>"Save Campaign"}
Unpermitted parameters: shorturl, owner
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "campaigns" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-10-18 01:04:08.211040"], ["updated_at", "2014-10-18 01:04:08.211040"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered campaign/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 112ms (Views: 108.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
::1 - - [17/Oct/2014:21:04:08 -0400] "POST /campaign HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.1166
```

But I have my params permitted properly (at least I think I do) according to my `campaign#controller`

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(shorturl_attributes: [:redirect], owner_attributes: [:email])
```

and my models:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shorturl
```

Why am I getting: `Unpermitted parameters: shorturl, owner` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionController::UnknownFormat` is raised when the action doesn't handle the request format.

Your controller only responds to JSON format, but your POST format is probably `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: To paraphrase the deleted comment: "I added `format.html` and now I'm getting `no attribute named: action`"  Response: Great!  So this question is answered.  It sounds like you're now running into a new issue with *strong parameters*.  That should probably be a different question.  Try reproducing the new issue in the console so you can write a more concise question.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment and updated the question with the latest events. I didn't want to confuse you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Do you know why I am getting this strong params error? Btw Adblocker blocks facebook and twitter icons from rendering on your site (http://www.jaredbeck.com/) An easy way to work around adblocker is to give tw/fb icons arbitrary names and no alt tags. Then they display properly.. +1 for the help! :)

Comment: I think I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shorturl` incorrectly. I'm just not sure how it ties together. If you know, please share! =D

Comment: If we discuss multiple issues in the same question, it will be less useful for other people reading this question.  Please create a new question for the next issue, or better yet, search to see if it has already been answered.  Please feel free to let me know when you've created a new question and I promise to help you with it!

Comment: No worries.. I was able to work it out. Thanks anyway!